# SharePoint Daily Employee Reports

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, sharepoint-foundation, custom-list, office-365-develop-tool

I need help to complete below requirement. I want to archive this using SharePoint 2013 OOTB Custom List or SharePoint Designer also fine.

Let me try to explain, A manager of a company having 50 engineers reporting to you. He has deployed SharePoint 2013 as a collaboration tool for document management. He want to incorporate a feature in SharePoint to record 50 engineers daily activities. So there should be a List which each engineer has to fill on daily basis and enter the following information.

- Name of Engineer - Jhon
  -Name of Manager - Clayton
  -9:30 am to 11:30 am - Jhon worked on interviewing with Client to cater new requirements in the CRM.
  -11.30 AM to 1.30 pm - Jhon went to Mcdonalds to deploy latest patch of CRM from the development team.
- 1.30 PM to 5.30 pm - Jhon prepared a new proposal based on Client interview for new CRM requirement.

Total Hours = 8 Hrs

the above mentioned example will repeated for every engineer who is working on different projects

so at the end of week/ month Mr. Clayton will be able to see each engineer activity with respect to project name, date or any other criteria. (that will be treated as reporting for managers).I hope this time i could explain the objective.

I want to archive this using SharePoint 2013 OOTB Custom List or SharePoint Designer is also fine.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SharePoint Foundation**

In case of foundation you can add a Task App. And add that app into the site home page. Then use it to manage activities of employees.

1. Manager can create task and assign it to employee
2. Employee can create there own task to keep track
3. The task list comes with due date and automatic reminders

**SharePoint Server**

You don't need to reinvent wheel because SharePoint comes with a site template which matches most of your requirements.

The template name is "[Project Site](http://blog.fpweb.net/understanding-sharepoint-2013-project-site-template/#.VGZfj_nF_To)"

The only change you need to do is add an extra column to the task list. Name it hours spend. Each employee should fill in that field as part of completing the task.

1. Manager can create task and assign it to employee
2. Employee can create there own task to keep track
3. The task list comes with due date and automatic reminders

You can create separate views for manager where they can see a total of the hours spend column. You can group by assigned to to find individual total etc.

Comment: Amal, Is this template available in SharePoint Foundation 2013.

Comment: @user3760253 my bad. I missed the foundation tag. Not its available only on the server. I will update my answer.

Comment: Its fine Amal.:).Can you please help me if I want to create using SharePoint OOTB Custom List is it possible. And can you please provide some rough idea to complete this task in SharePoint Custom List (OOTB).Thanks

Comment: @user3760253 why you need a custom list. Create an OOB Task List and add columns to that to full fill you requirements.